# Big O of Insert and Remove for a BST?

Tags: binary-search-tree

Big O of Insert and Remove for a BST? Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Simple hint: Google.com, and type in the title of this question.

Answer (score 4):

[image]


also check out the ppts on this website for Binary Search trees and other data structures.
http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS302/

Comment: `It varies based on the way the binary search tree is implemented?? ` And that comparison is between Array-based lists, Linked Lists and BSTs.